# Histogram problem using Python generator?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to generators and coroutines. Am trying to mimic the common histogram problem (given a list, return the occurences of each element in that list) using generators.

```
def genFunc():
    dct = {}
    while True:
        num = yield
        if num not in dct.keys():
            dct[num]=1
        else:
            dct[num]+=1
        print dct


g = genFunc()
next(g)

for each in [1,1,1,2]:
    print g.send(each)
```

With the code above, I am able to print out the state of dictionary "dct" at each stage. How do I return it to the calling func? If I use a return outside of the while block, I get error - cannot use return with yield.

As I understand, the value passed in send is received by the generator at the yield statement. In this case ideally I would want to pass a number/integer and get back the current state of the dict.

Comment: Are you using Python2? What's the reason? Python2 is EOL in ~18 days...

Comment: @AndrejKesely Will it suddenly stop working?

Comment: @Carcigenicate "There's no need to **use** 2.7" is a pretty bold statement. I have been working on a huge Python 2.x codebase with no intention to migrate to 3.x, so there is obviously a need.

Comment: @Selcuk I understand using Python2 when there's need to maintain legacy application(s). But learning it as "first" Python, no way...

Comment: @AndrejKesely Agreed. Though the OP stated that they are "new to generators and coroutines", not Python in general.

Answer (score 2):

`yield` "returns" the data back. You're using it to receive data from the caller, but it can also be used to send data:

```
def genFunc():
    dct = {}
    while True:
        num = yield dct  # I'm yielding the dictionary
        if num not in dct.keys():
            dct[num] = 1

        else:
            dct[num] += 1


g = genFunc()
next(g)

for each in [1, 1, 1, 2]:
    print g.send(each)

{1: 1}
{1: 2}
{1: 3}
{1: 3, 2: 1}
```

`send` returns what was yielded.

Comment: Thank you ! That helps.. I was confused with the send and yield ..